# Workaround to avoid JIT compile limit on Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, jit

i have a class that binds a obj-c object

```
public unsafe partial class CUSTOMER_INFO : NSObject {

        [Export ("signature", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
        get {
            NSData ret;
            if (IsDirectBinding) {
                ret =  Runtime.GetNSObject<NSData> (global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend (this.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("signature")));
            } else {
                ret =  Runtime.GetNSObject<NSData> (global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper (this.SuperHandle, Selector.GetHandle ("signature")));
            }
            if (!IsNewRefcountEnabled ())
                __mt_Signature_var = ret;
            return ret;
        }

        [Export ("setSignature:", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
        set {
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException ("value");
            if (IsDirectBinding) {
                global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr (this.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("setSignature:"), value.Handle);
            } else {
                global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.void_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr (this.SuperHandle, Selector.GetHandle ("setSignature:"), value.Handle);
            }
            if (!IsNewRefcountEnabled ())
                __mt_Signature_var = value;
        }
}
```

but when i declare it and i pass it to a method (inside a ios binding library), i get the known exception

> System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method
>   'CUSTOMER_INFO:set_Signature (Foundation.NSData)' while running with
>   --aot-only. See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.

**UPDATE** after suggestion by user @SushiHangover
In my iOS binding library project in generated code I tried this workaround:

```
[Register("CUSTOMER_INFO", true)]
//public unsafe partial class CUSTOMER_INFO : NSObject {
public unsafe partial class CUSTOMER_INFO_GENERIC<T> : NSObject where T : NSObject
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    static readonly IntPtr class_ptr = Class.GetHandle ("CUSTOMER_INFO");

    public override IntPtr ClassHandle { get { return class_ptr; } }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    [EditorBrowsable (EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [Export ("init")]
    public CUSTOMER_INFO_GENERIC () : base (NSObjectFlag.Empty)
    {
        IsDirectBinding = GetType ().Assembly == global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.this_assembly;
        if (IsDirectBinding) {
            InitializeHandle (global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend (this.Handle, global::ObjCRuntime.Selector.GetHandle ("init")), "init");
        } else {
            InitializeHandle (global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper (this.SuperHandle, global::ObjCRuntime.Selector.GetHandle ("init")), "init");
        }
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    [EditorBrowsable (EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    protected CUSTOMER_INFO_GENERIC(NSObjectFlag t) : base (t)
    {
        IsDirectBinding = GetType ().Assembly == global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.this_assembly;
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    [EditorBrowsable (EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    protected internal CUSTOMER_INFO_GENERIC(IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        IsDirectBinding = GetType ().Assembly == global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.this_assembly;
    }

    // other methods....
    // .................

    [CompilerGenerated]
    object __mt_Signature_var;
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public virtual NSData SignatureNoJit {
        [Export ("signature", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
        get {
            NSData ret;
            if (IsDirectBinding) {
                ret =  Runtime.GetNSObject<NSData> (global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend (this.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("signature")));
            } else {
                ret =  Runtime.GetNSObject<NSData> (global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper (this.SuperHandle, Selector.GetHandle ("signature")));
            }
            if (!IsNewRefcountEnabled ())
                __mt_Signature_var = ret;
            return ret;
        }

        [Export ("setSignature:", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
        set {
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException ("value");
            if (IsDirectBinding) {
                global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr (this.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("setSignature:"), value.Handle);
            } else {
                global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.void_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr (this.SuperHandle, Selector.GetHandle ("setSignature:"), value.Handle);
            }
            if (!IsNewRefcountEnabled ())
                __mt_Signature_var = value;
        }
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    protected override void Dispose (bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose (disposing);
        if (Handle == IntPtr.Zero) {
            __mt_Signature_var = null;
        }
    }
}

public class CUSTOMER_INFO_NOJIT : CUSTOMER_INFO_GENERIC<NSData>
{
    // A specialized subclass and this is passed to your ObjC-based method
}
```

But when i call

```
NSData tmp = NSData.FromArray(new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF });
CUSTOMER_INFO_NOJIT CustomerInfo = new CUSTOMER_INFO_NOJIT();
CustomerInfo.CardHolderEmail = CardHolderEMail;
CustomerInfo.CardHolderMobile = CardHolderMobilePhone;
CustomerInfo.SignatureNoJit = tmp;
```

I get this exception again:

> System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method
>   'CUSTOMER_INFO_GENERIC`1:set_SignatureNoJit
>   (Foundation.NSData)' while running with --aot-only. See
>   http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.

Anybody can suggest me a workaround/pattern to avoid this exception?
Thank you!

Lewix

Answer (score 0):

*(I might need more coffee...so take this with grain of salt... :-)*

This:

```
public unsafe partial class CUSTOMER_INFO : NSObject {
   ~~~~
}
```

Becomes:

```
public unsafe partial class CUSTOMER_INFO_GENERIC<T> : NSObject where T : NSObject {
  ~~~~
}

class CUSTOMER_INFO : CUSTOMER_INFO_GENERIC<NSData>
{
  // A specialized subclass and this is passed to your ObjC-based method
}
```

And thus `this` in your `set` and the `get` return can be resolved as `NSData` vs.  `NSObject` and no jitting is required and the compiler created/resolved the classes...

Comment: Hi @SushiHangover, can you check my updated post (thank you for your suggestion) and (i hope!) can you help me? I will offer a beer if you live near Italy :)

Comment: I tried to enable "Enable generic value type sharing" in ios project too

Comment: After a test on OSX platform, not JIT Exception happens, anybody can explain me why?

Comment: Any news about my question?

Comment: @LuiginoDeTogni Did not see your newer comments and updates... I'll take a look later... FYI: OS-X allows dynamic code gen/jitting so you would only see this type of issue on iOS...

Comment: Thank you @SushiHangover! Strange, this issue happens only on Visual Studio 2015 (Enterprise) in my Windows 10 Pro, not on OSX 10.11 as i said. Thank you again for any suggestion

Comment: @LuiginoDeTogni Confused... You mean as an OS-X native app, or as an iOS app being built and deployed from Xamarin Studio on OS-X?

Comment: I mean an iOS app being built and deployed from Xamarin Studio on OS-X

Comment: @LuiginoDeTogni Really confused now ;-) Do you have a sample project that reproduces this error when built from VisualStudio using a Mac built host vs. building on OS-X with Xamarin Studio?

Comment: i will try to prepare a simple project. As is it's a complex xamarin forms project and in iOS subproject is linked an further iOS binding library project